# Composite image with shadow catcher

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shadowcatcher, tilesize

So, while compositing a scene, seeing as DAZ models are kinda resource intensive, I tried to break it down into layers. The layers are combined using alpha over nodes and seem to be in the right order.
I cut out the floor of my set and put it with my model, making it a shadow catcher. Trouble is, when rendering, it doesn't catch shadows. Am I using the wrong nodes or something?
I'll upload the file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16TbsgbjojzedQ3enh2H4CbfOtqO3LOeG/view?usp=sharing
I have the shadow catching object set as a shadow catcher but when I render I see no shadow being cast by my figure, in fact watching the render, it never even tries to render a shadow- what's going on?
Also, how do you get the render view to render tiles?

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others 
downloading the file, or reading links, just to understanding the 
issue. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how 
you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)
that might help others understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Alright- I fixed it, best I know how. Sorry, last time I tried to ask no one would even consider trying to answer till I uploaded.